# How do I read the first line of lscpu?

Tags: bash, unix

I am learning bash right now on my own.

I'm trying to write an if else statement for a small script I'm writing. I want the script to read lscpu command to check if the system is an x86 or 64 bit system. Think you can help me?

Basically my script installs my favorite programs to an ubuntu system. Some of the programs are not in the depository and therefore you have to install offsite. However, some of them have different installer files for different architectures.

Pseudo code:

```
if [firstlineoflscpu = Architecture:          x86_64]
then install Blahblah
else blahblahblah
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
if lscpu | grep Architecture | grep -q x86_64
then
  # install 64-bit version
else
  # something else
fi
```

However, notice the `uname` command, which may be more direct:

```
$ uname -i
x86_64
```

Comment: So if I use uname:
`uname -i | grep Architecture | grep -q x86_64`

Comment: No, it would just be `uname -i | grep -q x86_64`.

Comment: So | is the equal operator in bash?

Comment: No, it is called the pipe.  It connects two commands by sending the output of (the left) one to the other as input.  The expression becomes an if condition because of the `grep`, which returns a true value if and only if a match was found.

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about bash, I highly recommend trying [this guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: I remember reading about the pipe recently, but I didn't know it can used like that. Thanks.

Comment: @munchschair And `=` is the equal operator, e.g. `if [ "$(uname -i)" = 'x86_64' ]; then #install 64-bit version`...

Comment: So you can do it either way.

Comment: @BroSlow True, but beware that `=` is not understood by the shell directly.  For that you need the `[` brackets, which is actually just an alternate name for the `test` program.

Comment: @munchschair Yes, `doing it in more than one way` is a fairly common feature of [tag:bash]

Comment: I'm learning java in school, just learning bash for fun. It's very handy with linux. I've been using linux for a decade and I've never really took advantage of it. feelsgoodman.jpg